# Extra space issue while creating a hard disk image using dd command

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, dd, disk

I have a Ubuntu OS installed on 1 Tb hard disk. Currently, around 200 GB hard disk is used while around 800 GB is free. Now, I have to take a complete (iso) image of hard disk for backup so that I can use this (customized) OS to another computer. From my search I have come to know that dd is the best command for this purpose. I have few question in this context

1. Is dd choice is correct option? if not, any other best option
2. To make image, do I need exactly same size external hard disk or small size also work (as used disk is just 200 GB right now)
3. Can I take image of disk in some folder instead of external hard disk
4. The created backup file could be booted in new computer system with new
   hard disk

Comment: `dd` does not create an `iso` image - also, `dd` works with `raw` data, be it a disk, a partition, a file ... it would not be the correct tool to create an image of just the "used" parts of a filesystem, i.e. the 200GB used of the 1000GB disk

Comment: Similar on SU: [Clone only space in use from hard disk](https://superuser.com/q/1097210/432690).

Answer (score 2):

1. `dd` *is* a tool for making sector-exact clones. Will it be the best choice, or even will it work for the particular scenario, depends on other requirements. If the requirement is to fit into a smaller device, `dd` is **not** the right tool to use. At least, not alone and not that simple.

   It doesn't analyze the structure of what it is copying. It doesn't have such a capability. All it does is take it sector by sector and write the copy in the same order. It has no way of determining which sectors are used by the underlying filesystem or even if there is any file system. It just copies devices as sequences of blocks.
2. An image (the copy) will be the same size as the source. A smaller device could in principle accept the large dump *only if* you use some kind of on-the-fly compression which will save space on the zero-filled or compressible blocks. For that to work, you need to *prepare* the source file system by really filling all unused blocks with zeros, otherwise they may still contain some garbage data left from the past when those blocks were in use, which could happen to not compress well enough.
3. You must not dump file systems mounted for writing. If you do, any write during the dump will render the dump inconsistent, and the file system in the dump will be corrupted. It is easy to arrange things so they will be even unrecoverable (in the dump). So before copying, remount it with read-only option, or pray it will still be in good shape. This implies that the dump could not be written to the same file system or same device, even in compressed form. You may dump over the network to another local device, internal or external, and so on, but not onto the same device.

   The best comparison is when you copy others notebook: you can sit down and rewrite it by hand, so rearrange to fill half-filled pages, not copy stroked text or marks or whatever you consider extra and then fit it into the smaller notebook, and even you can rewrite some pages into unused portions of the same notebook; or you can do "xerox" photocopy, in which case you'll have the image of the original, and it will use at least as much paper as an original. And you can't photocopy
   one side of the paper sheet onto another side of the same sheet, even if it's empty. `dd` is analogous to this photocopy: fast, easy, brutal.
4. This is when the dd could show some strength. It copies the structure together with the data; the clone will be indistinguishable from the original, so it will boot if the original was bootable on the machine.

---

You know, you may just copy the files with full permissions if you want to copy Linux. You need to create to partition the target device, create file systems, copy files, then set up booting of that new device. If you want to efficiently store your customized system as an image file which is possible to extract to any sufficiently large device, this is what `tar` tool is for. People use `dd` for system cloning because it takes substantially less work, despite its limitations.