# Is it possible to copy a disk image to a smaller disk?

Tags: mount, lvm, dd, cloning

Let me explain, for a greater detail (although this casuistry will serve for many more cases): I have a cloned image of a 512GB mSATA disk, which in practice, really dlos comanoes not reach 10GB used by the operating system (the rest is as free space yet). On the other hand, I would like to copy this image to a 256GB disk, also mSATA.

**Is there a way to instruct dd to copy only the part of the disk with content?**

The commands I have used to clone and copy are:

```
dd bs=512K if=/dev/sdx | gzip -c  > /image.img.gz
zcat /image.img.gz | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin mini.img
```

I have mounted and made modifications on `mini.img`, then:

```
dd bs=512K if=mini.img of=/dev/sdy
```

If I do it on a disk of similar size, of course there is no problem. However, if I do it over the bottom disk it does not throw error, but terminates.

But when I try to start the operating system, I run into this problem:

```
[...]
Begin: Running /scripts/iniy-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
done.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: error opening /dev/md?*: No such file or directory
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enought?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

In case it was of interest, at the time of the local disk mount, because it is Ubuntu with LVM2, I have made the following commands:

```
kpartx -a -v mini.img
vgscan
vgchange -ay
lvdisplay
mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv /mnt/ubuntu
```

Comment: In short: not with `dd`. `dd` is like copying a book page by page. Even if there are unused (empty) pages, fitting the book (partitions(s) with filesystem(s)) to lower number of pages requires modification of its table of contents. `dd` does not understand partition tables,  filesystems, "table of contents" nor such. If nobody answers and if no duplicate is found then maybe I will elaborate in a proper answer in several hours.

Comment: Please show output of `lsblk` on the source. Probably, you can only copy the partition or logical volume, perhaps resizing it down *prior* to copy. Also, this does look very much like this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731332/extra-space-issue-while-creating-a-hard-disk-image-using-dd-command

Comment: Basically, either opt for a file-based approach (i.e. rsync, tar, cp...), or make sure from the filesystems' POV (and in turn, from the partition entries') LBA greater than the end of the destination disk is no longer relevant before the image is written to it. (In the case of GPT, it should be 33 logical blocks less than the end, so that there will be "space" for you to recover the backup GPT on the 33 blocks at the end.) In other words, downsize the filesystem and partition (at the end) first.